# Аккордион на JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Делаю аккордион. Но возникает проблема - при целчке на "заголовке" он показывает то что нужно. Но как только мышку сдвигаем он сам закрывается. Как сделать чтоб он отображался а не скывался? а скрывался только при нажатии на другой элемент акоррдиона

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.content dd').hide();
    $('.content  dt').hover(
    function(){
    $('.content  dt').click(function(){
    $(this).next().show();
    return false;
    }).next().hide();
    });
    });

                </script>

<div class="content">
            <dl> Аккордион
            <dt>Новость первая
            <dd>Текст первой новости
            <dt>Новость вторая
            <dd>Текст второй новости
            <dt>Новость третья
            <dd>Текст третьей новости
            </dl>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content dd').hide();
    $('.content  dt').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
    return false;
    }).next().hide();
    });
```

Скрытие, при нажатии другого элемента додумаешь :)

Comment: насколько я понял автора - ему нужно, чтобы при наведении элемент показывался и оставался видимым до щелчка на другом элементе.

Comment: ну значит я слегка не допонял)

Answer (score 2):

Использовании метода `hover()` надо прописывать две функции: одну - для наведения, другую - для "отведения" мыши. У Вас, насколько я вижу, прописано только одно  - при наведении показывать элемент. поэтому второй (пустой) параметр применяет обратную функцию - скрыть. просто надо добавить вторую функцию, которая бы возвращала `return: false;`. Решение мне видется таким.

Ну, а чтобы по клику будет что-то приблизительно такое:

```
$('content dt').click(function(){
   $('content dt:visible').hide();
   $('content dt').next('dd').show();
});
```